# jquery width multiple ID different values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, width

thanks to some help i got around i made this jquery function that gets the sum of widths of IMGs within a DIV.

now i have a new problem:
multiple div.IDs with different widths, how can i make it most performant?

my code is this, for 1 div:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var widthSum = 0;
$('#oneid.scroll-content-item img').each(function(){
widthSum += $(this).width() + 20;
});
$( ".scroll-content" ).css('width', widthSum);
```

should i repeat this code several times with different IDs? if i make for example multiple selectors like this:

```
$('#oneid.scroll-content-item img, #twoid.scroll-content-item img').each(function(){
```

it will count them together, but i need separate.

any ideas?

thanks all!

Comment: Why don't you just get the width of whatever HTML element contains all the images? If there isn't one, put them in there. That way you can avoid having to fudge things (like with the `+ 20`).

Comment: It seems to me you're using an id like you should be using a class.

Comment: Example of using a container width: http://jsfiddle.net/eQXug/

Answer (score 2):

```
//this will go over any element with the class "scroll-content-item" seperately
$('.scroll-content-item').each(function(){
    var wrapper = $(this);
    var wrapperWidth = 0;

    //this will go over every img inside the seperate wrappers
    wrapper.find('img').each(function(){
        wrapperWidth += $(this).width() + 20;
    });

    wrapper.css('width', wrapperWidth);
});
```

Comment: hi! thanks, i'm using out this one now, trying to make it work. from what i understand the `.width() + 20` is for the margin, should I use something like `outerWidth()` and remove the +20?
it's almost 100% working

Comment: you could try using `.outerWidth(true)`, yes

Comment: tried that and + 20 together and i get a blank space after last img. if i remove +20 then the last image jumps to a 2nd row (on one div) and fits good on the other div ?!

Comment: hard to say without seeing an example what's the case here. can you set up something at jsfiddle.com?

Comment: yes, thats understandable. i'm using wordpress, would be a pain to move to jsfiddle. one demo site works perfect with one DIV. let me give it a few tries, maybe i can solve it on my own. anyways except the little blank space after last element, works perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWidth(elem) {
    var widthSum = 0;
    $('img', elem).each(function(){
        widthSum += $(this).width() + 20;
    });
    return widthSum;
}


$(window).load(function(){
    $('.scroll-content').each(function() {
        $(this).css('width', getWidth(this));
    });
});
​
```

Comment: still the same, no value returned